# why is this regex in C++ throwing an invalid range in bracket expression exception?

Tags: c++, regex

I am playing around with C++ regular expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::regex e("[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]");
   std::string str = "¡";//u00A1, trying to match this character
   bool match = std::regex_match(str, e);
   cout << match << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

The compilation failed with exception thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
what():  Invalid range in bracket expression.
```

I tested on regex101.com with:

```
[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]
```

and it gives me a match.

Also, is regex in C++ using the ECMAScript flavor?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `char` based regex but a 16 bit regular expression. Try switching to `wchar_t` as your character type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::wregex e(L"[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]");
   std::wstring str = L"¡";//u00A1, trying to match this character
   bool match = std::regex_match(str, e);
   cout << match << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion and it worked. I have a question: how did you tell that my regex is a 16 bit regular expression? Thank you

Comment: @peakpeaktan Because FFEF (for example) is a 16 bit number.

Comment: does it mean that you need to declare a std::wregex instead of std::regex if your regular expression involves Unicode?